# bash script showing file permissions gives wrong output

Tags: linux, bash

I am learning bash and wish you guys could help me out what's going on with the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

#primer if
if [ -f $file1 ]; then
        echo "file1 is a file"
else
        echo "file1 is not a regular file"
fi
#segundo if
if [ -r $file1 ]; then
        echo "file1 has read permission"
else
    echo "file1 doesnot have read permission"
fi
#tercer if
if [ -w $file1 ]; then
        echo "file1 has write permission"
else
    echo "file1 doesnot have write permission"
fi
#cuarto if
if [ -x $file1 ]; then
        echo "file1 has execute permission"
else
    echo "file1 doesnot have execute permission"
fi
```

It looks to me that it does not matter if I change the file permissions because output is always the same

```
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ ./script.sh 
file1 is a file
file1 has read permission
file1 has write permission
file1 has execute permission
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ ll file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 fmp fmp 0 Aug 30 13:21 file1
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ chmod 200 file1
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ ./script.sh 
file1 is a file
file1 has read permission
file1 has write permission
file1 has execute permission
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ ll file1
--w------- 1 fmp fmp 0 Aug 30 13:21 file1
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ chmod 000 file1 
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ ll file1
---------- 1 fmp fmp 0 Aug 30 13:21 file1
fmp@eva00:~/Books/2012/ubuntu_unleashed$ ./script.sh 
file1 is a file
file1 has read permission
file1 has write permission
file1 has execute permission
```

file1 can be empty or not and still output is the same, doing the same test

Can anybody explain to me what is wrong?

Thanks

BTW the script here is a modified version of compare3 on page 233 of ubuntu unleashed book 2011 edition (Book site http://ubuntuunleashed.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file1` variable is undefined.

you should add at the beginning of your script `file1="file1"`

Answer (score 3):

This is the reason all your tests are succeeding: since the variable is null, you get

```
if [ -f  ]; ...
if [ -r  ]; ...
if [ -w  ]; ...
if [ -x  ]; ...
```

Because you're using single brackets, bash only sees a single word for the test condition. When the test command sees only a single argument, the result is true if the word is not empty, and in each of these cases, the word contains 2 characters.

Of course the fix is to declare the variable. Also, you should be using bash's conditional construct

```
if [[ -f $file ]]; ...
if [[ -r $file ]]; ...
if [[ -w $file ]]; ...
if [[ -x $file ]]; ...
```

When the double brackets is used, bash will see 2 words in the condition even if the variable is empty or null.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `$file1` variable for `$1` or add the following at the begining of the script (after the #!/bin/bash):

```
set file1=$1
```

So you can invoke your script like this:

```
./script.sh file
```

Comment: set is for tcsh only or also bash?

Answer (score 2):

or remove the dolar sign, or replace `$file1` with `$1` and use the script as `./script.sh file1`